# Ruby Method Scope Issues

Tags: ruby, multithreading, scope

I'm learning ruby, and I'm trying to create a class in a module, and then use that class in another script. Here is my module:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

module RubyMine
  require 'thread'

  puts "loading"
  class Address
    def initialize(host, port)
      @host = host
      @port = port
    end

    def host
      @host
    end

    def port
      @port
    end
  end

  class Node
    def initialize(address)
      puts "Initializing..."
      @address = address
      @controller = nil
      puts "...initialized."
    end

    def stopin
      puts "Stopping..."
      Thread.kill(@controller)
      puts "...stopped."
    end

    def startin
      puts "Starting..."
      @controller = Thread.start do
        puts "Thread Starting..."
        listener = tcpserver.new(address.host, address.port)
        loop do
          Thread.start(listener.accept) do |s|
            loop do
              msg = s.gets.chomp
              break unless msg.length > 0
              puts msg
            end
          end
        end
        puts "Thread stopping."
      end
      puts "...started."
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, whenever I try to call `startin` or `stopin`, I get an error `./test.rb:8:in`': undefined method `startin' for #<RubyMine::Node:0xb243e8> (NoMethodError)`

Here is the script I'm using to call the module:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require '~/rubymine1/rubymine'

add = RubyMine::Address.new("127.0.0.1", 20000)
node = RubyMine::Node.new(add)
puts RubyMine::Node.methods
node.startin
sleep 4
node.stopin
```

I've been looking at examples and online tutorials, but as far as I can tell everything should be working. Any ideas?

-- Edit 5/14 --
Another thing that I forgot to mention, when I named 'startin' 'start', it ran. I think that's because it's overriding an existing method. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: Can you post your `test.rb` as is? I just ran your snippets and they work fine!

Comment: Are you sure the path `~/rubymine1/rubymine` really points to your module definition ? Just test with `RubyMine::Node.instance_methods.grep :startin` and you have to get matched result.

Comment: @rkon That is the entirety of the test. It's more of a napkin test than a unit test.

Comment: @DavidUnric I am. When I run it the constructor works and prints out the init messages, so I know that I'm loading the module.

Comment: @John regarding your guess about overriding an existing method: That cannot be the case, as otherwise you could never get a `NoMethodError` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, at least I could run it in irb without a problem. I could not telnet to the server though. For this reason I do not understand why you get the NoMethodError, I had none of these problems. However the line

```
puts RubyMine::Node.methods
```

would give you misleading results, as you are asking the *class object* about its methods. In order to know the methods of the `node` object you should ask it, e.g. as follows:

```
node.methods.select do |m| m.match /start/ end
```

(so you will only get one line of output, but the relevant one). As expected this displays

```
=> [:startin]
```

for me. Could you try that?

**EDIT**

As I said I ran this in an `irb` session of a `ruby` 1.9.2 I happened to have open in the Terminal and I got the following result:

```
irb(main):104:0> add = RubyMine::Address.new("127.0.0.1", 20000)
=> #<RubyMine::Address:0x007fbdaa8a05b0 @host="127.0.0.1", @port=20000>
irb(main):105:0> node = RubyMine::Node.new(add)
Initializing...
...initialized.
=> #<RubyMine::Node:0x007fbdaa898888 @address=#<RubyMine::Address:0x007fbdaa8a05b0 @host="127.0.0.1", @port=20000>, @controller=nil>
irb(main):106:0> node.methods.select do |m| m.match /start/ end
=> [:startin]
irb(main):107:0> node.startin
Starting...
...started.
=> nil
Thread Starting...irb(main):108:0> sleep 10

=> 10
irb(main):109:0> node.stopin
Stopping...
...stopped.
```

I think that should be what you would expect. Note however that I got

```
> telnet 127.0.0.1 20000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

even while the server was running. Maybe you can run your code in `irb` and you will see more of what might not work. You should also mention the version of ruby you are running on.

Comment: Tried that, and it didn't print anything out.

Comment: @John let me just clarify, if you added the line in your script it would not print anything as it just returns a methods array. For me in `irb` this is no problem as `irb` prints the return values of all statements anyway. If you put it in the script you would have to add `puts ` in front of it in order to see anything. You should at least see `[]` being printed, even if no methods can be found.